# Trying to list the resource groups and locations

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to list the Azure resource groups based on only the locations available in vnet locations. Here is my code.

```
$AllVnet=Get-AzVirtualNetwork
    $SelectVnet=$AllVnet | Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceGroupName,Location
    $vnetloc=$SelectVnet.Location  
    $ResourceGroupList=@()
    foreach($loc in $vnetloc)
    {
      
      $ResourceGroup=Get-AzResourceGroup -Location $loc
      $Name=$ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
      $Loc=$ResourceGroup.Location
      $VMObject = New-Object PSObject
      $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $Name
      $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Location" -Value $Loc
      $ResourceGroupList += $VMObject
    } 
    $ResourceGroupList
```

It returns the result in the below format

```
Name                                                           Location
----                                                           --------
AZRWUSRG1                                                      westus
{NWRG, AZREUS####, AZREU###, AZREUSLSSTO###} {eastus, eastus, eastus, eastus…}
```

But I want in this format

```
Name                                                           Location
----                                                           --------
AZRWUSRG1                                                      westus
NWRG                                                           eastus
AZREUS####                                                     eastus
AZREUSLSSTO###                                                 eastus
```

How can I achieve that? Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-AzResourceGroup` can return multiple objects of type `PSResourceGroup`. In this case `$ResourceGroup` will be an array.

> ```
> $Name=$ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName
> ```

The above code lets PowerShell create an array by collecting the value of the property `ResourceGroupName` from all elements of the array `$ResourceGroup`.  This is why you get output like `{NWRG, AZREUS####, AZREU###, AZREUSLSSTO###}`.

The code can be fixed and greatly simplified like this:

```
$AllVnet=Get-AzVirtualNetwork
$SelectVnet=$AllVnet | Select-Object -Property Name,ResourceGroupName,Location
$vnetloc=$SelectVnet.Location  

$ResourceGroupList = foreach($loc in $vnetloc)
{      
    Get-AzResourceGroup -Location $loc | Select-Object Name, Location
}
```

Using `Select-Object` we create a new object for each `PSResourceGroup` element that is returned from `Get-AzResourceGroup`, containing only the given properties.

Since we have assigned the `foreach` output to a variable, PowerShell automatically captures all output from the loop body in the variable, which will be an array when there are more than one elements.